# Can not search by Kata Kana (Japanese) 1 byte and 2 byte (ジ and ｼﾞ)

Tags: ios, swift

I have a list name by Kata Kana 1 byte (example ｼﾞ), I search by Katakana 2 byte ジ, but result is zero.
Do you know how to convert search text from Kata kana 2 byte to 1 byte? Please help me.

My code:

```
   let filteredData = searchText.isEmpty ? employeeList : employeeList.filter({(data : employee) -> Bool in

      return data.emp_name_kana?.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil

     })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Kata Kana 1 byte* is not an appropriate name for characters such as `"ｼﾞ"` in Unicode, better call it as Halfwidth Katakana as in the [Unicode standard](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFF00.pdf). Each of such characters cannot be represented using 1-byte in UTF-8.

You can apply some transform before comparing Strings:

```
let halfwidthKatakanaStr = "ｻﾞｼﾞｽﾞｾﾞｿﾞ"
let fullwidthSearchText = "ジ"

let found = halfwidthKatakanaStr.range(of: fullwidthSearchText.applyingTransform(.fullwidthToHalfwidth, reverse: false)!) != nil
print(found) //->true
```

(NOTE) The above code works in iOS9+, macOS 10.11+. If you need to target some older platforms, you may need to call classic `CFStringTransform`.